# Cannot ping FQDN, but can ping IP and can update

Tags: dns, ping, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 on machine behind a router and switch along with numerous other devices. Nothing is behind the server at this point (though everything used to be, thus the two interfaces configured as they are). All other devices work fine. I can ping IP addresses inside and outside the network, but cannot ping FQDN. Running `nslookup 8.8.8.8` and `nslookup google.com` gives me:

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
Server:         ::1
Address:        ::1#53

** server can't find 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL

;; Got SERVFAIL reply from ::1, trying next server
Server:        ::1
Address:       ::1#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p10p1
iface p10p1 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    network 192.168.5.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.5.255
```

My assumption is that there is a DNS problem here. I've purged/reinstalled dnsmasq, and it is pulling in the right nameservers from my ISP (since reinstalling dnsmasq I haven't fiddled with any of its files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry folks. I needed to edit `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` to have the correct nameservers in the forwarders block (I replaced the nameserver IPs with x's for this post):

```
forwarders {
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
};
```

Funny how something you've been messing with for so long just takes typing the question out to trigger the right research for the answer. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I also tried commenting out the forwarders block and that worked as well, FYI.